# Apply a bug-fix patch in Liferay 6.0.6 CE

Tags: github, liferay, liferay-6

I have a Liferay 6.0.6 CE deployed in my company. I just found out that "Overall Maximum File Size" can not be increased. Even if I increase the size greater than the default (104857600) it still throws me an exception saying as follows -

> 07:57:16,907 ERROR [UploadServletRequestImpl:101] org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (209715200) exceeds the configured maximum (104857600)
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (209715200) exceeds the configured maximum (104857600)

I found out that Liferay has fixed this bug and now I am unable to find the checkout branch for this particular bugfix. Infact I can't find a branch for 6.0.6 altogether.

Bug fix # LPS-13436 [Bug LPS-13436](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-13436)

Duplicate fix # LPS-17065 [Duplicated by LPS-17065](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-17065)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't find this fix in the 6.0.x branch is that these branches are no longer supported/updated. You'll be able to find the fix in trunk (or in the 6.1 codebase). I found two commits in https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal that were labelled with LPS-13436 - you'd basically need to backport them to 6.0.6 yourself.

One of the commits is [9711c0d77db2c5eb7043fcaccace75a7b89737b7](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/commit/9711c0d77db2c5eb7043fcaccace75a7b89737b7)

The alternative: Upgrade and stay on the latest version that still gets some updates - either CE (occasional updates until the next major version is out) or EE (service-level updates for up to 7 years from release)

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Great Help..!